# UWP ListView within ListView not respecting INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I am attempting to create a Windows 10 app to offer list of questions; each question displays the question text (TextBlock) and a list of possible answers (ListView pointing to a DataTemplate consisting of a ToggleButton).

The program starts and each Answer/PossibleAnswer is displayed, so far so good. Now I want to restrict each question to a single answer, which means when one PossibleAnswer (ToggleButton) is checked, the others for that question must be Unchecked.
The problem is this is not happening despite the fact I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the PossibleAnswer class and called the appropriate method. I even implemented this for the Answer class in the hopes it would help but it did not.

Am I doing something obviously dumb? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using ToggleButtons because checking a RadioButton in one question will uncheck the RadioButtons in all other questions.

My XAML file: (A ListView [For each question] pointing to a DataTemplate consisting of a TextBlock (Question text) and a ListView [PossibleAnswers])

```
<Page x:Class="QuestionsnAnswers.MainPage" ... >
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myAnswersTemplate" x:DataType="local:Answer">
            <RelativePanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionText}"/>
                <ListView Margin="0, 20 ,0 ,0"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleAnswers}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myPossibleAnswersTemplate}">
                </ListView>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="myPossibleAnswersTemplate" x:DataType="local:PossibleAnswer">
            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding PossibleAnswerText}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="PossibleAnswerClicked" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView Name="uiQuestionsnAnswers" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myAnswersTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My MainPage file: (A single page to demonstrate a list of Answers each with a list of PossibleAnswers)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //populate example answers
        Answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerId = 1, QuestionText = "Question 1" });
        Answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerId = 2, QuestionText = "Question 2" });
        Answers.Add(new Answer { AnswerId = 3, QuestionText = "Question 3" });
        uiQuestionsnAnswers.ItemsSource = Answers;
    }

    private void PossibleAnswerClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //get the reference to this togglebutton's PossibleAnswer and update the model.
        ListViewItemPresenter parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject) as ListViewItemPresenter;
        PossibleAnswer possAnswer = parent.Content as PossibleAnswer;
        possAnswer.IsChecked = true;
    }
}


class Answer : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    public int ChosenPossibleAnswerId { get; set; }

    public Answer() {
        PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>();
        PossibleAnswers.Add(new PossibleAnswer { ThisAnswer = this, PossibleAnswerId = 1, PossibleAnswerText = "yes" });
        PossibleAnswers.Add(new PossibleAnswer { ThisAnswer = this, PossibleAnswerId = 2, PossibleAnswerText = "no" });
        PossibleAnswers.Add(new PossibleAnswer { ThisAnswer = this, PossibleAnswerId = 3, PossibleAnswerText = "I don't know" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "") {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    internal void setChosenAnswer(int possibleAnswerId) {
        //record this possibleAnswer as the answer to this question.
        ChosenPossibleAnswerId = possibleAnswerId;

        foreach (PossibleAnswer possAnswer in PossibleAnswers) {
            if (possAnswer.PossibleAnswerId != ChosenPossibleAnswerId) {
                possAnswer.IsChecked = false;
                Debug.WriteLine("Answer " + AnswerId + " has unchecked possible answer " + possAnswer.PossibleAnswerId);
            }
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}


class PossibleAnswer : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Answer ThisAnswer { get; set; }
    public int PossibleAnswerId { get; set; }
    public string PossibleAnswerText { get; set; }

    private bool _IsChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked {
        get {
            return _IsChecked;
        }
        set {
            _IsChecked = value;
            if (value == true) {
                ThisAnswer.setChosenAnswer(PossibleAnswerId);
            }
            else {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "") {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, we can set the [Binding Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209829) of `IsChecked` to `TwoWay` like following:

```
<ToggleButton Click="PossibleAnswerClicked" Content="{Binding PossibleAnswerText}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

For [{Binding} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension#properties-of-the-binding-class-that-can-be-set-with-binding),  in most cases, the default mode is one-way. And it works well for read-only data. If we want the changes that the user makes to values in the UI are automatically pushed back into the data source, we need use two-way binding, and it works well for read-write data. If we use one-way binding here, the Binding will lose effect after user click the ToggleButton, thus your code won't work.